# Determine the convergence of the infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Determine the following infinite series is convergent or divergent.
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n-e\right]$$

Comment: «The ratio test is inconclusive. By the comparison test, the series diverges.» WolframAlpha.

Comment: What did you compare it with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It diverges.

Indeed, $$\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n-e\sim \frac{-e}{2n}$$

---

OP asked for details :

$\displaystyle \left(1+\frac1n\right)^n=\exp\left(n\ln\left(1+\frac1n\right)\right)=\exp\left(n\left(\frac1n-\frac{1}{2n^2}+o\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)\right)\right)$

$\displaystyle=\exp\left(1-\frac1{2n}+o\left(\frac1n\right)\right)=e^1 \exp\left(-\frac1{2n}+o\left(\frac1n\right)\right)=e^1\left(1-\frac1{2n}+o\left(\frac1n\right)\right)$

Hence $\displaystyle \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n-e = e^1 \left(-\frac1{2n}+o\left(\frac1n\right)\right)$

Hence  $$\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n-e\sim \frac{-e^1}{2n}$$

Comment: How did you get that?

Comment: @lovelesswang is that better now ?

Comment: But why is $\exp\left(1-\frac1{2n}+o\left(\frac1n\right)\right)=e^1 \left(1-\frac1{2n}+o\left(\frac1n\right)\right)$?

Comment: @lovelesswang I added an intermediate step.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks!